# CakePHP default flash doesn't always render

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm experiencing an issue in CakePHP 2.0 whereby my flash does not render as expected.  Consider the following example of my configuration:

app\View\Layouts\default.ctp:

```
<!-- flash echoed below -->

<div id="main_flash">
  <?PHP echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
</div>
```

app\View\Objects\index.ctp:

```
<!-- no flash echoed here -->
```

app\View\Object\edit.ctp:

```
<!-- flash echoed below -->

<div id="edit_flash">
  <?PHP echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
</div>
```

When I navigate to **mysite.com/objects/**, the flash (if set) successfully renders:

```
<div id="main_flash">Hello World!</div>
```

Now, whenever I edit an object **mysite.com/objects/edit/12**, the flash renders as shown below.  The flash wouldn't render at all before I added the echo to **edit.ctp**:

```
<div id="edit_flash">Hello World!</div>
```

Is there any way to have my flash always render from default.ctp i.e. without having to echo the flash in individual view files?  Right now, one flash statement works while the other is ignored.

Comment: Hello. First at all, you are using the reserved word 'Object' that is a class on CakePHP

Comment: The file names above are not actually used in my setup.  I just used 'Object' as an example.  That was probably confusing.

Comment: How are you setting the flash messages in each controller?

Comment: I was echoing the flash in my default layout / views.  I'm not sure why, but a fresh copy of CakePHP with my views pasted on top again solved the issue.